# Application.Quit not quitting the running app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code that shows me the time counting in the console, but it would not quit the program when it reaches 10 seconds. Am I missing something?

```
void Update ()
{
    Debug.Log ( Time.timeSinceLevelLoad );

    if ( Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > 10 )
        Application.Quit();
}
```

Comment: have you tried `Environment.Exit(0)` also put break points in your code an make sure it's hitting the code that you are expecting..

Comment: Thanks for this. It highlights it red. Do I need a specific directive for it?

Comment: did you add the `;` at the end of `Environment.Exit(0);` edit your code and show exactly what you have written.. also show the using section at the top of your .cs file.. make sure you have the following `using System;`

Comment: Wait, are you running this in the Unity editor?

Comment: @Jtech please clarify if this is a Console app or a Unity3d application thanks

Comment: Thanks Max (and everyone). I was missing the `System` directive, and I learned that `Application.Quit()` only works in a build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Quit` won't work in the editor:

> [Quit is ignored in the editor or the web player.](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.Quit.html)

If you want to test the behavior of quitting the game, just build it. If you want to quit the editor, use [`EditorApplication.Exit`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication.Exit.html) from the editor script.

Answer (score -1):

if this method is within a Console App change the method signature below from 
`void Update()` to `private static void Update()`

```
void Update()
{
    Debug.Log ( Time.timeSinceLevelLoad );
    if ( Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > 10 )
    {
         System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this question is about Unity project and not a console app

Comment: I am not sure but it's hard to determine since it's tagged C# and unity if it's unity the Op can reference this site [Unity Scripting](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.Quit.html)

Comment: Btw, I don't think that `System.Environment` is even fully supported in Unity's version of Mono. I would refrain from using `System` when the same capability exists in Unity's API, it's support is much better.

Comment: @MaxYankov I think you're correct however I wonder how what he was doing worked when I recommend he add using System I would expect that to have not worked either.. it's good info that you've provided as well thanks

Comment: @MethodMan: Thank you for your helpful suggestions. It was a Unity3D application that I wanted to quit both in editor and in standalone. Got it working now, using `Application.Quit ();` and `EditorApplication.Exit (0);`

Comment: Not a problem @Jtech it was hard to tell initially but glad that I was able to provide  you with a place to start

Comment: Downvoted, question is tagged Unity, answer is not about Unity but .Net

Comment: Unity hangs if i call Envrirnment.Exit()